# R: relative frequency in a table

Tags: r, probability, frequency, probability-density, frequency-distribution

I am working with quantil binomial and runif functions with R to simulate values.

My goal is get relative frequency with this function. The frequency that I get are ok, but the the relative frequency are wrong, example:

## Edit: I forgot add set.seed, but in my task I put in my script

```
set.seed(123)

table(qbinom(runif(1000,0,1),6,0.2))
```

## Frequencies:

```
 0   1   2   3   4   5 
277 367 245  88  22   1
```

#Relative Frequencies ???? wrong???

```
table(qbinom(runif(1000,0,1),6,0.2))/1000

  0     1     2     3     4     5     6 
0.271 0.402 0.239 0.071 0.014 0.002 0.001
```

My expected results are

```
  0      1      2     3     4       5 
0.277 0.367 0.245 0.088  0.022   0.001
```

I am ok?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`runif` is a random function, every time you run it you will get a different value. You are very unlikely to get the same value twice when you run `table(qbinom(runif(1000,0,1),6,0.2))` twice. For example if I run this a few times I get

```
table(qbinom(runif(1000,0,1),6,0.2))
#   0   1   2   3   4   5 
# 260 390 250  87  12   1 

table(qbinom(runif(1000,0,1),6,0.2))
#   0   1   2   3   4   5 
# 297 367 239  78  17   2 

table(qbinom(runif(1000,0,1),6,0.2))
#   0   1   2   3   4   5 
# 263 395 243  81  17   1
```

Dividing by 1000 will give relative frequencies for a particular instance.

If you want to get the same values, you could set your random seed before you call `runif`. For example

```
set.seed(616)
table(qbinom(runif(1000,0,1),6,0.2))
#   0   1   2   3   4   5 
# 270 383 248  76  22   1 

set.seed(616)
table(qbinom(runif(1000,0,1),6,0.2))
#   0   1   2   3   4   5 
# 270 383 248  76  22   1 

set.seed(616)
table(qbinom(runif(1000,0,1),6,0.2))/1000
#     0     1     2     3     4     5 
# 0.270 0.383 0.248 0.076 0.022 0.001
```

Or just save your random values

```
set.seed(616)
rand_vals <- runif(1000,0,1)
table(qbinom(rand_vals,6,0.2))
#   0   1   2   3   4   5 
# 270 383 248  76  22   1 

table(qbinom(rand_vals,6,0.2))/1000
#     0     1     2     3     4     5 
# 0.270 0.383 0.248 0.076 0.022 0.001
```

Comment: Thanks I forgot add set.seed in the loop

Comment: you need to call `set.seed` before every time you call `runif` if you want the same values. If you call it one without `/1000` and once with `/1000` that's two different calls which will result in different values. If you only have `set.seed(123)` once at the top, then you will still get different relative frequencies. It's better to save your random values when you generate them rather than trying to regenerate the same values each time.